# File move/copy progress tracking

Tags: android

Is there any way to track file copying progress with the info like remaining time, copying speed?
And I mean some "framework" way, without messing with inputstreams and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of anyone, but it should not be that difficult. Here is an [example for Swing](http://www.cs.ust.hk/~liao/comp201/slides/html/CopyFile.html) you could easily adapt. In Android the CopyFileTask would be an AsyncTask, that would publish the updates by means of publishProgress() instead of updating directly the progress bar (that would be carried out inside onProgressUpdate).